# Exchange distribution group alias restriction - can it start with an @ character?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, distribution-lists

At a previous employer a few years ago, all Exchange distribution groups were created such that the first character of the alias (the name you see in Outlook) began with an @ character. The distribution group's email address was often the same name WITHOUT the leading @ character. This convention made it very easy to identify distribution groups from within Outlook.

For instance, we had a distribution group for all developers with the alias `@DevelopmentTeam` and the email address `DevelopmentTeam@companyxyz.com`.

I'm now working at a different company, and would like to implement the same kind of thing, but I'm being told that Exchange doesn't allow distribution group alias to start with an @ character.

Either I'm not remembering things correctly, I'm being mislead, and I need to know which it is.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Alias cannot begin with nor include the @ character. The Display Name can. My guess is that you're conflating the Alias and the Display Name from your previous Exchange environment.